# How to invalidate object in Apache Ignite cache

Tags: caching, ignite

I would like to try implementing **read-through = true** and **write-through = false** cache. My application will read objects from cache and perform creates and updates directly to 3rd-party database (oracle).

How to tell Apache Ignite that I had updated object in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove an entry from the cache, using `IgniteCache#remove`, for example. It will be reloaded from the DB during next access.

Comment: Do you know if I can use sql DELETE instead?

Comment: If you use SQL to query data, then CacheStore read-through won't be applied. It works for Java API only.